# How to migrate a Project from 'OpenShift Web Console' to '(Next Gen) Web Console'?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Is there a way to migrate a server application (with its repository), to the new `Next Gen Console`?

I have already a WildFly server in my personal account at URL: https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/applications

But when I open the Next Gen Console, it's empty, and suggest me to create new project with a new server.
https://console.preview.openshift.com/console/

**Is there a way to avoid setting up everything again?**
I would like to keep server configurations, git repository, and Jenkins app from my former `OpenShift Web Console`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no direct migration tool. The manner in which the systems works is quite different from an operational standpoint, but you are also potentially going to have to tweak how your application code is organised and configured. I would suggest you create a fresh application in the new version to learn more how they are different and then you can plan what you may need to do to migrate it. I would suggest making using of the Google Group for OpenShift if you have more questions as it provides a better forum for discussion.

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openshift

Comment: Thanks. I have joined the group. Nevertheless, I think there should be a tool for facilitate management on Git repositories between both consoles.

Comment: Did you by chance accidentally delete the post? It came through in email via the group but doesn't show in the web interface. The group is set up right now so that can only post via the web interface, so unable to reply. Trying to get group changed to allow posts by email. I can then explain some stuff around handling Git repositories more.

Comment: Thank you Graham, yes, I deleted the question because I was able to solve it. Now I came up with another one, I am going to post it. Regards.